# CSS Fixed Header Top:0;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Working on a site and I am trying to make it so the `<header></header>` and navigation's remain at the top of the site. I am able to do so with some issues that i can't seem to resolve.

The code I am using is:

```
header {
    background:#000;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```

Now once I place this code in, every thing blow or not with in the `<header>` tag falls under the ''and also scrolls under and through the  as if passing through it. I am wondering if there is a way to get the rest of the site to fall bellow the '' or scroll with with out going under or through the `<header>`?

I have tried giving the `<header>` `<margin-bottom>` to create space so that text is visible when the site first loads but this doesn't seem to work out.

Any links to solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

Just put some height on the header and margin on the body.

```
header {
    background:#000;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    height: 60px;
}

body {
    margin-top: 60px
}
```

Comment: Added the: 'body {
    margin-top: 60px
}' and got the results i needed! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Give `header` a `z-index:9999` so that it is always comes on `top` of contents also give a `min-height:50px`, hope it solve your issue :)

**Thanks**

```
header {
background:#000;
position:fixed;
width: 100%;
min-height:50px;
padding:50px 10px 5px;
top: 0;
left:0px;
z-index:9999;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever wraps your content aside from the header give it `padding-top: [height of header]`. This will avoid it from being overlapped.